# 404 redirect on structure site not working

Tags: structure, 404, pages

...or only "partially" working.

My issue is if someone types in a non-existant url using an existing template group like this:

www.mysite.com/existing_template_group/cvgdghdbhbcdbcdh

The results are it will pull up index.html for existing_template_group and try to load ALL of the entries I have in the database. The curious thing about this issue is it only occurs with 3 out of 8 template groups in my site.

The other template groups seem to trigger the custom template (404/index) just fine.

If anyone can give me any insight to what the problem may be I'd appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had pages in Structure that had the same name as a template group.

About us page: www.mysite.com/about-us
Template group name: about-us.group

So if someone were to type in www.mysite.com/about-us/ccgsdcedh EE would look in the about-us template group and display the index template with all of my entries.

My solution was to change the names of the conflicting template groups to something no one would ever guess.